# Angular 6: How to include html file into component?

Tags: java, angular, jsp

In a servlet environment we can include any `jsp` like this :

```
<%@include file=" 'path-to-jsp' " %>
```

In my angular project I have a html form with many components in it.
I want to include this form in 2 components (create and update).

user-form.html :

```
<input type=".."...>
<input type=".."...>
<input type=".."...>
<select>...
```

create-user.component.html:

```
<form>
   // insert content of 'user-form.html' at compile time
   <button>Create User</button>
</form>
```

update-user.component.html:

```
<form>
   // insert content of 'user-form.html' at compile time
   <button>Update User</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this in Angular 2+ ?

note: I use reactive forms

Comment: If you want bindings to work out off the box I'd say you have to make a component for form.html and include that component in your create/update components

Comment: Looks like that, I need to make a new component for that. Or I duplicate the code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Wolf359 Any update on this ? I want to load file2.component.html content in file1.component.html

Comment: @Ramkee, no, I stopped looking for a solution. Also, it's not included in Angular for a reason I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [innerHtml] in a **`create-user.component`** with something like

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-template',
    template: `
<div [innerHtml]="myTemplate">
</div>
`})
export public class MyTemplate {
    private myTemplate: any = "";
    @Input() url: string;
    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.myTemplate = yourHTMl); //Load it using http
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't do, because I need the bindings to work. But this could come in handy with other problems. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can add this **user-form**  as a template in your view. in this way binding will also work
Like the following example

```
<user-form [state] = 'Create/Update'></user-form>
<button>Create/Update</button>
```

and the user component will take the state as an input to check whether it's in edit or create state.
And mention the selector as "user-form" in the UserFormComponent and also include UserFormComponent in your current component.