# how to include html file as we do in angular js but in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have on common component , one parent and child HTML FILES.
If we want to include html file in angular 1 we used ng-include. Now in angular 6 /5/4 want to include only HTML .I don't want to create separate component and add selector . i just want to give url to html if certain conditions matches.

I have included PNG file which is part of main common html on click of section 1 want to pass url of html and it should redirect to that part .BUT NO SEPARATE COMPONENT . Any solution?[img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZTAZ.png)

Comment: If it's pure HTML, and doesn't contain any Angular markup, then just use Http to get them like you would with any other data you want to download, and then display that HTML using innerHTML. Otherwise, forget it: that's not how Angular works: templates need to be compiled.

Comment: actually you can get component's html template decorator during runtime as long as it is inline html template and not path to a separate file, but this is risky as angular team might change it anytime in the future.

Comment: it's the same for angular 5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50538705/angular-6-how-to-include-html-file-into-component